# How does the compiler know what the endianness will be?

Tags: c++, optimization, endianness, bit-shift

I thought of using tests at runtime to determine the endianness so that I can be sure of the behaviour of shifts, and noticed a somewhat peculiar optimization by my compiler. It would suggest that the endianness of the machine it will run on is known at compile time.

These are the two routines I timed. Routine 2, which makes use of const, was about 33% faster.

```
/* routine 1 */
int big_endian = 1 << 1;
for (register int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
  int value = big_endian ? 5 << 2 : 5 >> 2;
  value = ~value;
}
/* routine 2 */
const int big_endian = 1 << 1;
for (register int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
  int value = big_endian ? 5 << 2 : 5 >> 2;
  value = ~value;
}
```

The speed of routine 2 matches that of using a constant expression computable at compile time. How is this possible, if the behaviour of shifts depends on the processor?

Also, on a side note, why do we call numbers that end with the *least* significant digit *big* endian numbers, and those that end with the *most* significant digit *little* endian numbers.

**Edit:**

Some people in the comments claim bitwise shifts have nothing to do with endianness. If this is true, does that mean that a number such as 3 is always stored as `00000011 (big endian)` and never as `11000000 (little endian)?` And if this is indeed the case, which actually does seem to make sense, wouldn't it act weird when using little endian, since `10000000 00000000 00000000 (128)`  shifted to the left by one would become `00000000 00000001 00000000 (256)?` Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for trying stuff and measuring it.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with endianness. The value of `big_endian` will *always* be 2, no matter what the endianness of the target system is.

Comment: Side note answer: because little-endian numbers *start* with the least-significant digit.

Comment: I've always thought of it as short for "X end first", as in "big end first" or "little end first". If you think it terms of big beginning and little end, then yes it will fly backwards for you.  Maybe we should all change to "big beginian" and "little beginian" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Just as the Lilliputians started eating their eggs at the little end, little-endian machines start storing their integers at the little end (less significant bytes). The Blefuscudians started with the big end, just like big-endian machines put the big end first.

Comment: Additional info:  Here is a link to the paper that (I believe) is where endianess started.  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien137.txt

Comment: The behavior of shifts is in no way dependent on endianness. Endianness only matters if you do something like treat an array of char as an int.

Comment: and as @Rob Kennedy points out it is a reference to Gulliver's Travels.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. However, these answers clear the path to new questions. Please look at my edit for more information.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler always knows the target of the build as the instructions, and endianness are specific to architecture.

Most of the time, the target is the one of the current machine or a more generic one, unless you are cross-compiling.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler assumes an endianness for the target processor.  Most of the time this is obvious, for example x86 is always little-endian.  For architectures which could be either, there is often a compiler switch if the default doesn't work for you.  For example, gcc/arm has `-mlittle-endian` (default) and `-mbig-endian` flags.